# PHP - Architechtural advice needed with FTP streaming

Tags: php, ftp

I've built an application which interacts with a web camera via FTP, however upon completing it I have a speed issue. The application structure is as follows:

Web Camera -> Proftp/Mysql -> PHP

The web camera ftp's images to the Proftp server which is managed via MySQL / PHP. The PHP acts as a client for users, and it in turn pulls the latest images from the FTP server.

This works, but is really slow. The problem is on the Proftp -> PHP side. Using the standard PHP ftp library it takes around 4 seconds to connect to the ftp server -> do a directory listing -> output the file contents.

The speed issue is due to the authentication part of the process. From what I've seen there's no way of caching/storing/serializing the FTP connection, meaning every request to the server has to start a new request.

These are the thoughts I've had so far..

1) Have a PHP script run in a while loop with a permanent FTP connection open, but I know PHP isn't designed to be run in this way.

2) Create a daemon running node.js / java etc which is able to keep a permanent ftp connection open, and have PHP interact with that. What I'm worried about with this approach is the extra maintenance involved in writing more code which duplicates the authentication code already written in PHP.

3) ???

Any help / suggestions would be greatly appreciated!.

Comment: If you are looking for something in PHP to run as a daemon you could run time based jobs using http://prggmr.org/modules/time/api.html, this would allow for keeping a connection open for periods of time. You would just need to manage this using something such as runit.

Answer (score 0):

won't it be wise to schedule it on cron job to enable the FTP script to run nearly permanent, or at a given short interval?

Comment: The FTP script doesn't actually need to download any files. In just streams the file contents out. For instance my image urls are <img src="/path/to/phpcontroller/?timestamp"> and then I use setTimer to refresh the image.

Answer (score 0):

Why you go the extra mile to read the images from ftp?

If they are on the same server, just read them via php directly from the storage directory.

If they are not on the same server, utilize some mechanism to inform php about the latest image (for example via a text file, a GET variable etc.) and directly output http/ftp image.

Comment: There could be xxxx number of cameras using multiple ftp servers, so the FTP servers will be separate from the PHP side. I could use a text file / or I guess change the home directory for each user and mount the FTP drives over the network.

Comment: Mounting the drives via network is significantly faster than opening a connection each time indeed. You just get a large number of open connections. Another idea would be to try and get the cameras to somehow push the photo to a php script which will accept them and overwrite the older ones, while they stay saved on the specific ftp anyway.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I believe the new firmware versions of the software allow precisely that!

Comment: You're welcome. If the firmware supports it, then this will be by far the best solution.